# Assign values to a variable with do loop in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with column names payment_201601, payment_201602, ..., payment_202112.

I would like to convert these columns into two columns, payments and paymonth.

This is what I came up with:

```
*ARRAY payment {12} payment_201601-payment_201612;
DO i = 1 TO 12;
IF payment{i} > 0 THEN DO;
payment=payment{i};
paymonth=201600+&i;
END;
END;*
```

However, the code only worked for payment but not for paymonth. The paymonth variable contains only missing values in the output.

Grateful for any help or a better way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome :-)

There are several reasons why your code does not work. The main thing is that you can not mix data step and macro code in this way. Macro code runs before you data step even compiles.

Instead, use all Data Step code and do something like this. I assume that you want Paymonth to be an actual date variable. I just made up some sample data.

Feel free to ask.

```
data have;
array p payment_201601 - payment_201612;
   do _N_ = 1 to 10;
      do over p;
         p = rand('integer', 1, 100);  
      end;
      output;
   end;
run;

data want;
   set have;
   array p payment_201601 - payment_201612;
   do over p;
      payment = p;
      paymonth = input(compress(vname(p),, 'kd'), yymmn6.);
      output;
   end;
   keep payment paymonth;
   format paymonth yymmn6.;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Draycut! Your code worked perfectly and helped me progress my work. Much appreciated!

Comment: Anytime :-) Please remember to mark the answer as a solution. This helps future users navigate.